# How do we call a class without passing variables on the call?

Tags: python

Here is a MRE:

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self, action, name):
        self.action = action
        self.name = name

    def name_dog(self):
        my_name = input("give me a name: ")
        return self.name(my_name)

    def act_like_dog(self):
        order = input("Tell me to do something: ")
        msg = self.name + " is " + order
        return self.action(msg)

    def main(self):
        self.name_dog()
        self.act_like_dog()

Dog.main()
```

The main objective for calling the dog class in this case is for the user to input their own values (name, action) for the class. So the variables for the class I specified (`Dog` class) are obtained from a function call (`self.name_dog` and `self.act_like_dog`) in the `main()` function, which prompts the user to give his/her input. However when I tried calling the `main()` function without `self`, I got an error saying a positional argument is needed, while if I called the function `self()`, an error says that `self` is not defined. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need an instance. Something like `Dog().main()`

Comment: What do you expect `self.name(my_name)` to do?

Comment: And you'll need to pass `action` and `name` as in `Dog('bark', 'fido')`, unless you give them default values in the `__init(...)__` method.

Comment: @jarmod Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of prompting the user?

Comment: It would then make more sense to put the prompts in the `__init__`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo wouldn't it return the name value prompted from the user? or should i drop the my_name and just return the name value directly?

Comment: `Dog.main()` you should use this when using the static method call and in static method call you don't have to use `self` either, else I suggest using `Dog().main()`

Comment: @YubarajShrestha When I do this pycharm tells me it lacks positional arguments for "action" and "name"

Comment: `Dog().main()` would not work since the `Dog` class expects two params to initialize.

Comment: @penjelmaankatak Can you describe what your objective is? This sounds like a [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Are you trying to ask the user what the `Dog` `action` and `name` is _before_ initializing the class? The following two lines; `return self.name(my_name)`, `return self.action(msg)`, are in themselves incorrect (would not work).

Comment: @penjelmaankatak yes I am aware of that as well. But I might be wrong to think that all your methods in that specific class are dependent on those variables `action` and `name`. So did you finally tried this `dog_object = Dog('action', 'name')` and then `dog_object.main()` ?

Comment: @Felipe pointed the right thing here.

Comment: @Felipe The main objective for calling the dog class's main() function in this case is for the user to input their own values (name, action) for the class. Or is this fundamentally wrong for classes?

Comment: It is possible, but `.main()` is not needed. See my answer for reference.

Comment: You should not call `input()` from methods in the Dog class. The class should be standalone and represent a dog, its attributes, and actions. You would call `input()` from your mainline code and then either create a dog with the relevant attributes or invoke the relevant action on an existing dog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confused about a few elements.

You need to create an actual instance of the class to be able to class its methods - `Dog(...)`. Apart from that, there is a logical problem where you expect to create an instance with `name` and `action` but then take them as inputs from the user. I think what you should do is simply set the attributes with user input in the `__init__`. Something like:

```py
class Dog():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = self.name_dog()
        self.action = self.act_like_dog()
        
    def name_dog(self):
        my_name = input("give me a name: ")
        return my_name

    def act_like_dog(self):
        order = input("Tell me to do something: ")
        msg = self.name + " is " + order
        return msg

dog = Dog()
```

If you want to be able to change the `name` and `action` later, you can use your `main` idea:

```py
class Dog():
    def __init__(self):
        main()

    ...

    def main():
        self.name = self.name_dog()
        self.action = self.act_like_dog()

dog = Dog()
```

Comment: Can't we put all of these functions into one main function? So when we call the main function, name_dog and act_like_dog will also get called as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like so:

```py
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, action=None, name=None):

        if name:
            self.name = name
        else:
            self.name = input("Dog's name: ")

        if action:
            self.action = action
        else:
            self.action = input("Dog's action: ")

d = Dog()
# ... or ...
d = Dog("Max", "Bark")
# ... or ...
d = Dog("Max")
d = Dog(name="Max")
# ... or ...
d = Dog(action="Bark")
```